# How to export apk for publich google play store in eclipse

Tags: android

Can anybody tell How to export apk for publich google play store in eclipse

Thanks

Comment: Ever heard of Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all you need is a credit card, your appication's .APK file and 2 screenshot of app

then follow these instructions

[Publish Your Andriod App in Play store](http://www.instructables.com/id/Publishing-an-Android-App-to-the-Google-Play-Store/)

Cheers...........

Answer (score 4):

you go through following links....

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tHyLHn9Ht6w

http://www.flipcreator.net/icreateapp/submit-to-googleplay.html

it will definitely help you.....best luck